# ASP.net DropDownList not working with WebBrowser OCX control

Tags: asp.net, webbrowser-control

For some reason the ASP.NET DropDownList control does not work properly with the Microsoft WebBrowser OCX control.  Clicking on any of the options from the drop down list has no effect.  However, when browsing the page using a regular browser it works as expected.

I've recorded a GIF of the behaviour (the "Unregistered" text is the watermark of the software I used):

[image]

The only way to select different options is by using the keyboard, but that's not acceptable for us.

Possible solutions to this problem are posted here:

http://scn.sap.com/message/13775661

Unfortunately, we cannot modify the registry settings of all the clients.  Is it possible to fix this problem from within the ASP.NET application or maybe the application that is hosting OCX control?